# Relative Path for WSDL in CXF Webservice Client

Tags: wsdl, cxf, relative-path

In my Application I use many Webservices. As the WSDL does not change, I have integrated the WSDL files in my project. If I use the WSDL2Java Tool from CXF, the WSDL locations absolute path is hardcoded.

Now my Question is, how to change the "wsdlocation" parameter in the @WebserviceClient Annotation to a relative path?

Here is a example:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Time", 
                  wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Users/dominik/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Webservices/src/wsdl/Time.wsdl" ) /*I want this path to be relative */
public class Time extends Service {
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this correctly today. Just put the files is your resources folder and then you can use wsdlLocation to refer to them relatively like this:

```
<wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/myservice.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
```

See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875701/1190144

Comment: Combine <wsdl> with <wsdlLocation> because if you use it only the <wsdlLocation> not works!

Comment: Sadly this fails for me on version 3.4.4 of the plugin due to "Invalid WSDL URL: classpath". If I remove the classpath: it prefixes the full path which isn't correct for the deployment

Answer (score 2):

Here is what one can do for generating an empty wsdl location

```
<wsdlOptions>
  <wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/service.wsdl</wsdl>
    <extraargs>
      <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
      <wsdlurl />
    </extraargs>
  </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

The client then can receive the wsdl location as an argument and become an portable client. That's why I was looking for use an relative path: achieve an portable client

Comment: Take care that with this method the policies present in the WSDL are not used.

Answer (score 0):

The wsdl2java tool has a -wsdlLocation flag that  can be used to specify the exact string that is placed in there.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I want to set the wsdlLocation to a relative path.