# Relative placement of wsdl-files in Java SOAP clients

Tags: java, jboss, wsdl, cxf, wsimport

Is it possible to make Java SOAP clients using local WSDL-files, so that the references to them are relative to the "client", at not absolute, both in stand-alone applications and Java EE, and across operating system?

I use WSIMPORT to generate artifacts, and it seems the resulting service needs access to the wsdl to initialize. How can I specify wsdl-location to be relative to the project it resides in? That means packaged in a JAR/WAR and relative to operating system (Linux/Windows) and relative to execution environment (Java EE server vs. stand alone application).

Comment: I have used the solution presented in [How to avoid the need to specify the WSDL location in a CXF or JAX-WS generated webservice client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455195/how-to-avoid-the-need-to-specify-the-wsdl-location-in-a-cxf-or-jax-ws-generated) with success. The `classpath:` prefix in the `wsdlLocation` property works with the CXF codegen Maven plugin, but perhaps a similar approach can be used with `wsimport` (or then you can switch to using CXF, which is a good framework BTW).

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the current artifacts af created with CFX, so the code looks pretty similar to the one posted in the solution. I should be able to just edit the current code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the file as a resource from a location that is on your classpath. Examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file).

By ensuring your build process always bundles the file into your JAR at the same location, you can access the file in the same way anywhere in your code.

Comment: Does this mean the wsdl-files should be placed in both 
   `src/main/resource/wsdl`
and
   `src/test/resource/wsdl`
to have junit to work as well?

Comment: Yes. It is also common to use a different wsdl file for tests (eg pointing to a UAT or Prod parallel environment.   However, you would need to check if src/main/resource is also on the classpath when you run your tests - I'm not sure what the default settings are here but normally I think only the test resources will be added in test configurations.

Comment: I am trying to build a generic client to be used in many of our project. If needed, the client can be initialized with a custom wsdl from outside classes/packages. If none is specified, the client should default to it's own wsdl. I have tried a Junit-test, and the placement of the wsdl-file in the `src/main/resource` is used for the tests as well. So all is well. Thanks!