# Initilize constant on if java

Tags: java, annotations

I have class:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Test", wsdlLocation = ????)
public class WSSerfvice
    extends Service
```

To wsdlLocation I need to set variable, value of the variable will set by case. **But my `wsdlLocation` ask my for a constant**, by I don't know for sure which value I will have to set to wsdlLocation

I have Global class wher I set wsdlLocation for class above to  set ???:

```
        String wsdlLocation;
        if(env.toLowerCase().equals("case1")) {
            wsdlLocation = "case1"
        } else (env.toLowerCase().equals("case2")) {
            wsdlLocation = "case2"
        }
```

If I make wsdlLocation **final** compile exception.

How can I set variable to my ???? in annotation

Comment: [Same issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455195/how-to-avoid-the-need-to-specify-the-wsdl-location-in-a-cxf-or-jax-ws-generated) - solved using cxf-codegen-plugin and "classpath:wsdl/FooService.wsdl" as wsdlLocation value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to be possible to modify constant field value in runtime, because it was inlined during compilation. Even reflection won't help.

For your case, IMO, it is preferrable, to set `wsdlLocation` to the relative path, pointing to the wsdl file in your classpath. In that case, you are able to provide different wsdl files, according to your environment. You can find a number of examples, how it could be done for your web service implementation.